# App Keeps Respringing When Launched

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

For some reason, whenever I try to run any app created in Xcode (even brand new ones), something happened (?) and now Springboard takes up a ridiculous amount of CPU until it launches. Once it's launched it's fine, but until then it will often respring if there's not enough memory. It runs fine in the Sim, just not on the physical phone. No clue why. I can provide logs or info, I'm just not sure what to put here; I've looked at most logs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to run the app? On a real device or in the Simulator? If you're using a real device, unplug it, open `/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` and delete the folder with the iOS version of your device. After that, reconnect it. Does that help?

Also, please provide any logs you get and information about your system versions, devices and the Xcode version.